# JUnit4 vs JUnit5 with spring-boot-starter-test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

The `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency adds both JUnit4 vs JUnit5 APIs

[image]

Is it OK if developers start using both and any?
Are there any problems expected when codebase have many both JUnit4 vs JUnit5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is part of JUnit 5's vintage component that has backwards compatibility for JUnit 4

Comment: JUnit 5 Vintage Component provides a test engine for JUnit 3 as well.

Comment: Yes, it is so. But this is not answer if it is good idea to use them together.